Issue with Latex bibliography template
I have previously never run into issues with Bibtex, but I am attempting to use a template and my citations are now showing as (?). Below is my Latex code:
\documentclass[aoas]{imsart}

%% Packages
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}%% uncomment this for coloring bibliography citations and linked URLs
\RequirePackage{graphicx}%% uncomment this for including figures



\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

Test test \citep{RN263, RN127}

\bibliographystyle{imsart-nameyear} 
\bibliography{refs}{}  

Here is my Bibtex file (called refs):

@Article{RN263,
   author = {Albert, H. and Nathavitharana, R. R. and Isaacs, C. and Pai, M. and Denkinger, C. M. and Boehme, C. C.},
   title = {Development, roll-out and impact of Xpert MTB/RIF for tuberculosis: what lessons have we learnt and how can we do better?},
   journal = {Eur Respir J},
   volume = {48},
   number = {2},
   pages = {516-25},
   DOI = {10.1183/13993003.00543-2016},
   url = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27418550},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN127,
   author = {Aung, S. T. and Nyunt, W. W. and Moe, M. M. and Aung, H. L. and Lwin, T.},
   title = {The fourth national tuberculosis prevalence survey in Myanmar},
   journal = {PLOS Glob Public Health},
   volume = {2},
   number = {6},
   pages = {e0000588},
    DOI = {10.1371/journal.pgph.0000588},
   url = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/36962394},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

The .cls, .sty, and .bst files can be found here: https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.ims-aap/
Many thanks in advance!

Are you working locally, or on Overleaf?  If locally, are you compiling with pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex?  What does your log file say?

if you get ? it means there is no bibliography so either you did not run bibtex or you got an error, show the bibtex log (.blg) file in your question.

your test file has no \end{document} so produces no output at all,
